# Set button text without the use of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, button

I've been trying to create a new button and then set its text without the use of innerHTML. I tried the setAttribute but maybe that does not work or perhaps my syntax was wrong. Could someone tell me if it is possible to achieve and if so, how I can do it. This is the code:

```
var newButton = document.createElement("button");
var newerButton = document.createElement("button");

newButton.innerHTML = "Skicka";         // This I want to avoid
newerButton.innerHTML = "Stäng";

newButton.className = "popupButton";
newerButton.className = "popupButton";

newButton.setAttribute("id", "Skicka");
newerButton.setAttribute("id", "Avbryt");

myDiv.appendChild(newButton);
myDiv.appendChild(newerButton);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `innerHTML`?

Comment: You can use `input type button`

Comment: `newButton.innerText = "Skicka";` ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with innerHMTL, but I'm in a class where we should learn to do it without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a text node child should do it:

```
var buttonText = document.createTextNode("Skicka");
newButton.appendChild(buttonText);
```